# White space between data and axis when using pcolor in octave

Tags: plot, octave

I am trying to create a colorplot using pcolor. I want to use "shading interp" so am not using imagesc(). However when I set the axis manually the plot has white space between the data and the axis.

I want to zoom into one section of the data rather than the whole image. (This problem does not occur when the matrix and using "axis("tight")  )

Thank you in advance for your help

The code I am using is :

```
clf
load x.dat;
load y.dat;
load 15-1-14_E2_lam_7410nm.txt

x=x;
y=y;
A=X15_1_14_E2_lam_7410nm;

A=rot90(A);

h=pcolor(x,y,A);
shading interp
set(h,"EdgeColor",'none');
axis([60 90 -20 20])
#axis("tight")
colorbar
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the white space at one or more axis edges is because your data does not go fully to the edge of the frame (or the axis) you are setting. This can happen frequently when using something like meshgrid() to set the frame from -L to L in steps dl but then your data may start at -L and only go to, say, L-dl.